# How do I return back specific data from a csv?

Tags: java, file, csv, read-write

I've written code based on the exercise question but it's not returning the correct the number. It feels as if I did everything right.

```
 static double Q3(String stockFilename, String date) {

    // Given a filename with stock data in the format "date,price,volume" and a date, return the total value of all
    // shares of the stock that were traded that day. The total value is price times (multiplication) volume.

    String line = "";
    String dataArray[];
    double price = 0.0;
    double volume = 0.0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(stockFilename));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            dataArray = line.split(",");

            if(dataArray[0].equals(date)) //Finds the date of that day
                price = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[1]); //Grabs price 
                volume = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[2]); //Grabs volume
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return price*volume;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Incorrect on input: [data/FB_2016.csv, 2016-02-12]
Expected output : 3.6903954403536E9
Your output     : 3.8674439998248E9
```

As you can see it's returning back a very similar number.

Comment: Hint: we have no idea of what the file contains. But you seem to assume that the file only has one row for a given date. And you ignore all but the last one found, so...

Comment: The first step in solving your problem will be to isolate your problem, meaning it's time to do some serious debugging, either with a debugger that will allow you to step through your code and analyze variables as the program progresses, or with a logger, or with a "poor man's debugger" -- a lot of println statements that expose variable state as the program progresses.

Comment: You should also stop using C/Pascal habits of declaring all the variables at the top of the method. Declare them only when they're needed, in the narrowest scope possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a several mistakes in your code.

1) You need totalAmount instead of single price and volume.

2) In your if() are missed {} (`volume = Double.parseDouble(dataArray[2]);` is always executed)

As result, you return [last price in given day] * [last volume in file]. I think, it's a bit different than you expect.

3) So, your code should be something like this:

```
double totalAmount = 0.0;

...

if(dataArray[0].equals(date)) {
  totalAmount += Double.parseDouble(dataArray[1]) * Double.parseDouble(dataArray[2]);
}

...

return totalAmount;
```

In this case totalAmount is sum of price * volume for all records for given day.